# Using p:picklist to a large item list

Tags: primefaces

I have the current code to get a list of item using a picklist in Primefaces:

```
    <p:pickList showSourceFilter="true" showTargetFilter="true" filterMatchMode="contains"  label="#{msg.dataview_label_net}" id="pickListNet" converter="firstItemConverter" value="#{dataViewBean.net}" var="node" itemLabel="#{item.name}" itemValue="#{item}" />
```

But, I have an issue with performance at the Google Chrome to show this list.

My backend is fast, but, to show all item in Primefaces there is a long time to render. Is it possible using some pagination in a picklist or some like lazy load?

I have around 3000 items in my list. I tried a js fix to improve in here:
https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20TargetVersion%20Reporter%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=7655

but it's not working good for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution for this issue is try another component like a `DataTable`.

I used a DataTable with a multiple checkbox and a lazy scroll to show only a partial list. My time to load reduce from 1min15s to 15s.

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry this is not supported in the versions of PrimeFaces at this time of writing (5.1/5.2-SNAPSHOT). As could have been found out by lookin at the PrimeFaces documentation

Comment: Maybe, I should really use something like Datatable instead it.

Comment: Yes, that is an option that was also mentioned in the PrimeFaces forum several years ago. But other options like rethinking if you realy need looooooong lists in a picklist should be kept open to. Thinks like filtering upfront (dividing the list in groups) could be more user friendly

Answer (score 1):

i'm using primeng and i've faced the problem of pagination, i bring data from API, by 20 elements each call, the solution was to get the list element UL of  the source by className and check if scroll is in the limit, if yes i make a new call of the api with page+1 and concatenate the data